# How to update DB context class in .Net Core using database first approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an application in ASP web forms. I working on migrating this web form application to .net core 3.0. **I am using database first approach** as I have perfect tables structure, many store procedures and too much data.
Today I add some new columns in data table 'Stock'.
Columns name are:

1. Color_ID.   2. Location_Id

I also add one new table 'Locations' in my database.
Now the question is how can I update the DB context model class in my project for this two tables changes using database first approach in .net core.

Answer (score 5):

### Scaffold Context

Using the Package Manager Console

```
Scaffold-DbContext "your_connection_string" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force
```

using CLI

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "your_connection_string" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -f
```

### Updating the Context

if you want to re-scaffold the model after making schema changes, you can do so by specifying the -force option e.g.:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "your_connection_string" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -force
```

All of the class files will be overwritten, which means that any amendments that you might have made to them e.g. adding attributes or additional members, will be lost.

Comment: Saeed Gholamzadeh Sir, Will this commands also import my sql store procedures in the model context class. I mean only tables models will update or store procedures also?

Comment: in aspnetcore you can't scaffold context with db first store procedures instead, you can use context to call procedure like this approach: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx